# UIContainerView Not responding to touch after event iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to implement a drawer UIContainerView that allows the user to expand and contract it to reveal information.  I have the container view set up and the button to "expand" is working fine.

However, once the view is 'expanded' it no longer responds to touch.   It has a text view and two buttons.  Even more; when I touch the screen it registers as a tap on the collectionView behind it, and NOT the buttons that I'm supposed to be able to interact with.

This is the code handling the parent / child relationship with the container view:

```
// Parent View Controller.h
{
UIViewController *child1;
profileDescriptionViewController *profileDescription;
}

// Parent View Controller.m
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    child1 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"profileDescription"];
[child1 didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}

// Child View Controller.m
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
_profileDescription.text = [[dataHandler getAthlete] profileDescriptionString];
_isExposed = NO;
_frame = self.view.frame;
_height = _frame.size.height;
_yOrigin = _frame.origin.y;
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
- (IBAction)profileExpand:(id)sender
{
if (_isExposed == NO) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^
     {
         //0, 487, 320, 32
         [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(_frame.origin.x, _yOrigin - 100, 320, _yOrigin + 150)];

     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished)
    {
        [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
         _isExposed = YES;
     }];
}
/*    else
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^
    {
        [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(_frame.origin.x, _yOrigin + 100, 320, _yOrigin - 150)];
    }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished)
    {
        _isExposed = NO;
    }];
}*/ 
}
```

I just want the view to respond to touch events. It's not being placed behind any UI elements on the `parentViewController` but I can't select either button at the top or the description, and instead it interacts with elements behind it.

Anyone have any ideas as to why this would be?  In storyboard its set up like a regular container view.

Comment: You have "interactions enabled" on this view?

Comment: I have `userInteraction: YES` on the viewDidLoad method in the child view controller

Comment: maybe your frames calculation is wrong. set clips to bounds on the view to check it. sometimes frames are too small so that views are visible but not touchable.

Comment: Just set clips to bounds to `YES`.  No change.

Comment: maybe you can upload a dummy project to test it.

Answer (score 0):

I met a similar problem, the reason is the super view is not big enough, so after expand the subview, you can see it, but it not responding to any touch event. You can set the clipsToBound of the super view to NO to check it. Hope this helps.